# Proper implementation of IPv6 for LAN when having Dynamic IPv6 address from ISP

Tags: routing, ipv6, isp, mikrotik

I have a working IPv6 setup with LAN and WAN interfaces.
However, there is challenge since ISP provides the Dynamic IPv6 address (range) instead of static (I do not know why?).

So, any time the WAN IPv6 address range changes for me (from the ISP), LAN devices are unaware of the change and unable to go to IPv6 internet until they get the new IPv6 address as well.

What is the proper solution for handling such issues?

Network LAN clients are complaining that "the internet stops working", since they cannot continue web surfing because google.com and other services are resolved and returning IPv6 address (like they should), however their lan-client device hasn't change the local ipv6 address.

I am using RouterOS 7 and have current config:

```
# For WAN interface I receive whole /56 range from ISP and put to "my-ipv6-pool"
/ipv6 dhcp-client add add-default-route=yes interface=WAN pool-name=my-ipv6-pool request=address,prefix use-interface-duid=yes use-peer-dns=no

# I need my Router to have IPv6 address on LAN and WAN interface
/ipv6 address
add from-pool=my-ipv6-pool interface=LAN
add from-pool=my-ipv6-pool interface=WAN

# I do not use DHCP Server for my LAN devices, instead i use IPv6 ND, maybe adjusting timing is needed?
/ipv6 nd set [ find default=yes ] other-configuration=yes ra-interval=30s-1m
/ipv6 nd prefix default set preferred-lifetime=5m valid-lifetime=10m
```

Btw, I do not want to use some local static IPv6 address range for LAN and then doing src-NAT.

I have this situation on multiple locations, sometimes is also Cisco IPv6 router, but same issue.

Comment: Home networking is offtopic on Serverfault. However - look at PD: https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=179358

Comment: This is the work related, but in home-office. Anyhow network setup / configuration is the same. I have commented on Mikrotik forum also, but the question is in general for network specific (same issues happens on the cisco ipv6 router etc.), how should be implemented for concrete case when ISP provides dynamic instead of static IPv6 address

Comment: Most equipment supports grabbing the prefix handed out. Specifics vary from vendor to vendor. The relevant thing is to understand prefix delegation.

Comment: MikroTik RouterOS is updated instantly, problem is on client device (windows, android) that needs to refresh IPv6 address "now", otherwise ipv6 internet stops working

Answer (score 0):

It seems like well-known issue when using dynamic IPv6 ranges from ISP and IETF provided some workaround options in section 5 - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gont-6man-slaac-renum-01#section-5

Permanent solution would be the router needs to support RFC 9096 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9096 which is basically newer version of previous RFC6204.